# Group by Sum for Calculated field in Linq

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, linq

I want to get create a calculated field for a three way join between tables. The three tables are named Recipes, Ingredients and IngredientsToRecipes. The values that these tables carry are as follows:

Recipes

- recipeID
- userID
- name
- description

Ingredients

- siin
- name
- price
- description

IngredientsToRecipes

- siin
- recipeID

Now, I started off by doing a three-way join and then grouping by recipe since there would be many duplicates from the join, here is how I did that:

```
var recipesJoin = (
    from a in db.IngredientsToRecipes
    join b in db.Recipes on a.recipeID equals b.recipeID
    join c in db.Ingredients on a.siin equals c.siin
    select new
    {
        recipeID = a.recipeID,
        userID = b.userID,
        name = b.name,
        description = b.description,
        price = c.price
    }).GroupBy(x=>x.recipeID);
```

My plan was to then create a new table from recipesJoin whereby I would sum the price up and then only return the rows that have price below a variable y. I've tried many things but my understanding of Linq started today so I'm severely limited.
I tried

```
var recipesJoin = (
    from a in db.IngredientsToRecipes
    join b in db.Recipes on a.recipeID equals b.recipeID
    join c in db.Ingredients on a.siin equals c.siin
    select new
    {
        recipeID = a.recipeID,
        userID = b.userID,
        name = b.name,
        description = b.description,
        price = c.price
    }).GroupBy(x=>x.recipeID).Sum(y=>y.price);
```

but I get the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'IGrouping>' does not contain a definition for 'price' and no extension method 'price' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) SalWebAPI   C:\Users\Samuel.endeva\source\repos\SalApp\SalApp\SalWebAPI\Controllers\RecipeTypeBudgetController.cs   31  Active

I don't quite understand the error. My main goal is to sum and group into a calculated field, remove the rows that are above a certain price and then join that new table with another to do a simple check. How do I do the sum for a 3 way join like this?

Comment: *"I don't quite understand the error."* After you apply GroupBy you're getting groups and they don't have price. The group knows its key and items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should select the result after the grouping action. Since you are grouping by recipeID I believe you want the sum price for each unique recipe ID as a result here is the proposal:

```
var recipesJoin = (
      from a in db.IngredientsToRecipes
      join b in db.Recipes on a.recipeID equals b.recipeID
      join c in db.Ingredients on a.siin equals c.siin
      select new
      {
          recipeID = a.recipeID,
          userID = b.userID,
          name = b.name,
          description = b.description,
          price = c.price
      }).GroupBy(x => x.recipeID) // 1
          .Select(grp=> new //2
          {
              recipeID = grp.Key,
              name= grp.First().name, // same ID => same name anyway
              toalPrice = grp.Sum(b => b.price) //3
          })
          .Where(y => y.totalPrice < 2000); //4
```

1- group by recipedID

2- Select result to get different entities for each unique recipe ID

3- Here you can do the sum for each unique recipeID (got though y.Key==grouping key)

4- Filter the results (replace 2000 by your real threshold)

Comment: Would it be possible to add name = y.Key and for it to automatically pull out name from the Key?

Comment: Since you are grouping by recipeID you have a group of object linked to a unique recipeID, but you can select the name of the first object assuming that it will be the same for the whole group. I will edit the example I gave

Comment: Oh so if I did still need to pull that data, I could just join it with the recipe table and voila I guess?

Comment: Well, you don't necessary need it, because it's already done in the initial join statement. If you need another data from recipe you use the same solution described for Name (add it in a separate field in the *select new* statement, and then select the final value after the grouping)